# Why is the $90$ degree clockwise rotation matrix not representative of the locations of $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, rotations

I was watching a 3Blue1Brown video on inverse matrices and he showed that a $90$ degree counterclockwise rotation has the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 &-1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ which makes sense to me since it represents where $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$ land. But then he shows the inverse matrix that represents a clockwise rotation, with the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ which does not correspond to $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$. Why is this?

Comment: I assume you meant to typeset the matrices as being 

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad
R^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: When you do $R^{-1}\mathbf i$ and $R^{-1}\mathbf j$, do the results match where you expect $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ to land?

Comment: The columns of the second matrix do correspond to where the basis vectors(which you refer to as i hat and j hat) get mapped to. Namely, the vector $(1, 0)$ after a rotation of $90$ degrees gets mapped to the vector $(0, -1)$ and the vector $(0, 1)$ after a rotation of $90$ degrees gets mapped to the vector $(1, 0)$.

Comment: oh I get it now - you multiply the values of i and j after applying R by R inverse in order to get the pre-transformation values of i and j. thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us label the matrices by

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad
R^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\newcommand{\i}{\hat\imath}
\newcommand{\j}{\hat\jmath}$$

Note that the first column responds to where $\hat\imath$ goes, and the second where $\j$ goes, after applying the matrix to $\mathbb{R}^2$ in its normal state.

So:

- $R$ sends $\i$ to $(0,1)$, matching a $90^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation
- $R$ sends $\j$ to $(-1,0)$, likewise matching
- $R^{-1}$ sends $\i$ to $(0,-1)$, matching a $90^\circ$ clockwise rotation
- $R^{-1}$ sends $\j$ to $(1,0)$, likewise matching

You can play with this in [this Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iihmkrusvp), which essentially rotates a given vector $(a,b)$ by a more general rotation matrix. Some notes:

- It assumes a rotation by $T\pi$ radians counterclockwise. $90^\circ$ clockwise corresponds to $3\pi/2$ radians counterclockwise as a result.
- The red vector displayed is the original, and the black the result.